# Is this layout for a food search engine easy to scan (are the important elements properly focused)?

Tags: website-design, search-results

[image]

I'm making a design for a client. This is the first time I design for a search engine.

I would like to know if the elements in the design below are easy to scan (are the important ones properly focused)?

Comment: My Chinese is little rusty, so i can't tell if you are emphasizing the important elements.

Answer (score 1):

- **On what basis are the results sorted?** I think you need to highlight that.
  I know it's usually by search term relevance, but since price and some other info is mentioned, it may be a good idea to confirm.
- If you expect the users search for something generic like 'BBQ' then
  there needs to be a way for them to sort the results. Maybe **give
  users options to sort by price or distance.**
- **'find' can be replaced by 'Search Places'** to give a
  more accurate purpose. Unless ofcourse you can search for other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

- I can't tell which ones that are important. Might be a language issue?
- Are all prices red (=low)? If not could they be put into any context? If so you could use different colors on the map markers?
- I suppose that you will highlight the marker on the map as you hover its name in the listing?
- You could try using clusters? Not sure how that might affect hovering and highlighting though. [Demo 1](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html) / [Demo 2](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/toomanymarkers/toomanymarkers.html)

Also:

- The search icon in the search box is redundant as the find button is next to it.